# How do I make a database transaction atomic (all parts complete or none of them)?

Tags: database, transactions

Let's say, I have one saving account and one checking account. My saving account balance is 150$. I am trying to transfer 100$ from my saving account to checking account, also transfer 100$ from my saving account to my friend's account.

**Steps for transferring 100$ from my saving account to my checking account:**

1.1. Read(current_saving_balance)

1.2. Reduce saving_balance by 100

1.3. Add 100 to my checking_balance

**Steps for transferring 100$ from my saving account to my friend's account:**

2.1. Read(current_saving_balance)

2.2. Reduce saving_balance by 100

2.3. Add 100 to my friend's account balance

I want to execute these transactions concurrently. If they both read saving_balance in the beginning, both will be able to reduce saving_balance by 100$, but, only one of them should be able to succeed. How's this taken care of in banking systems.

Comment: Use the "serializable" isolation level.

Comment: You need to specify your database platform. Transactions are implemented differently in each one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for serializable isolation level (however the exact loggin semantics are very different from database system to database system).

- Do a select for update as the first statement and then perform the rest of the transaction.
  The first transaction to execute the select for update will lock the row, the other transaction will be blocked, until the first one commits (pessimistic locking)
- Make sure that when the update statement is executed it still has the same value as when it was read, otherwise re-execute
- There is no need to explicitly read the data, a simple update statement is sufficient (however there needs to be logic that checks for sufficient funds in the account, this can be achieved with a trigger).

Answer (score 0):

You have tow actual transactions (1. transfer $100 to checking. 2. transfer $100 to friend)
and what you are trying is making it in single technical transaction (begin;...;commit). I think this is wrong method. Your code must reflect the actual transaction i.e. 
Begin; ... 1. transfer $100 to checking. ;commit;
Begin; ... 2. transfer $100 to friend). ;commit;
Have some database function which will check the balance before every transaction and make a decision whether to save or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in tSQL, your database may vary in syntax.

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE  accounts
SET balance = balance-100
WHERE   account='1'

UPDATE  accounts
SET balance = balance + 100
WHERE   account='2'

COMMIT TRAN
```

I suggest you read [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions) to understand DB transactions more.

Ignore the whole serializable isolation conversation going on in the comments. It doesn't really address the problem you described.